# React Hooks: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, react-hooks, use-effect, web-frontend

by using voila with foreach I think the state has been manipulated...
So help me to find out what is the actual problem...
like I tried to use loop which didn't worked inside the loop and know I tried with foreach and it tell that map is undefined, probably because the state is manipulated...
Moreover, do see the console.log in the useeffect which gives me the thing that I want. But with that same logic I can't render it in the page.

```
      export default function App() {
      const [selectedUserName, setSelectedUserName] = React.useState("");
      const [tvShow, setTvShow] = React.useState(thestack);
      const [selectedTVShow, setSelectedTVShow] = React.useState("");
      useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedUserName !== "") {
          setTvShow(() =>
            thestack.filter((show) => show.username === selectedUserName)
          );
        }
      }, [selectedUserName]);
      useEffect(() => {
          if (selectedTVShow !== "") {
          let voila = [10]
          // for(let i=0;i<10;i++){ 
          setTvShow(
             voila.forEach(function (number) {thestack.filter((showme=[number]) => {return showme.sitcoms[number] === selectedTVShow})  })                 
            // thestack.filter((showme) => showme.sitcoms[2] === selectedTVShow)
            );
              // }
          }
        for(let i=0;i<10;i++){console.log(thestack.filter((showme = [i]) => {return showme.sitcoms[i] === selectedTVShow}));}
        
      }, [selectedTVShow]);
      let summedArray = thestack[1].sitcoms.concat(
        thestack[2].sitcoms,
        thestack[3].sitcoms,
        thestack[4].sitcoms,
        thestack[5].sitcoms
      );
      //console.log(summedArray)
      let newsummedArray = [...new Set(summedArray)];
      //console.log(newsummedArray);
      // console.log(thestack[3].sitcoms[3]);
      let vola = newsummedArray.map((element) => {
        return element;
      });
      //console.log(vola)
      return (
        <div>
          <select
            placeholder="Sitcoms"
            onChange={(event) => setSelectedUserName(event.target.value) }
            
          >
            <option value="nothing">Select the username</option>
            <option value="priyansh__8">priyansh__8</option>
            <option value="shekhar_mandal_">shekhar_mandal_</option>
            <option value="h28h8_00">h28h8_00</option>
            <option value="iamneegam">iamneegam</option>
          </select>
          <span> </span>
          <button className="reloadButton" onClick={() => setTvShow(thestack)}>
            Reload
          </button>
          <select
            placeholder="TVShow"
            onChange={(event) => setSelectedTVShow(event.target.value)}
            className="TVdropdown"
          >
            <option>Choose any TV-Show</option>
            <option>{newsummedArray[0]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[1]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[2]}</option>  
          <option>{newsummedArray[3]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[4]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[5]}</option>  
          <option>{newsummedArray[6]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[7]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[8]}</option>  
          <option>{newsummedArray[9]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[10]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[11]}</option>  
          <option>{newsummedArray[12]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[13]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[14]}</option>  
          <option>{newsummedArray[15]}</option>  <option>{newsummedArray[16]}</option>  
          </select>
    
          <div className="App">
            {tvShow.map((item) => (
              <Square
                key={item.id}
                icon_six={item.icon[5]}
                username={item.username}
                username_link={item.username_link}
                icon_one={item.icon[0]}
                sitcoms_one={item.sitcoms[0]}
                icon_two={item.icon[1]}
                sitcoms_two={item.sitcoms[1]}
                icon_three={item.icon[2]}
                sitcoms_three={item.sitcoms[2]}
                icon_four={item.icon[3]}
                sitcoms_four={item.sitcoms[3]}
                icon_five={item.icon[4]}
                sitcoms_five={item.sitcoms[4]}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: What is `theStack`? What is to be your expected result of `voila.forEach(function (number) {thestack.filter((showme=[number]) => {return showme.sitcoms[number] === selectedTVShow})})`?

Comment: thestack is the name of the main object array, and I want it to display the contents in that multidimensional array....

Comment: What is "main object array"? Can you update your question to include all relevant code enough for a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://github.com/randomrajan/sitcomstack/blob/master/src/thestack.js